# Draw a ER diagram using Draw.io

Tags: python-3.x, draw.io

My aim is to draw a ER diagram for a natural language scenario. I already implemented some part of that using python. For drawing an ERD I used draw.io CSV file importing option.
[image]

The implemented code generate the file which can draw a diagram from the above option but the problem is I want to manually copy the generated file content and paste it into the draw.io window.

[image]

I want to know is there any method which I can use for automatically do the copy and paste part using python or are there any methods for drawing an ER diagram easily?

Comment: So you want to generate a csv file with python, then use draw.io to create the diagram based on that csv? If draw.io does not have any API capable of doing this, maybe try using selenium.

Comment: Run your own version, https://github.com/jgraph/drawio, and programmatically insert the CSV.

Answer (score 0):

Best I've came accross was editing the xml files in python: just build a diagram template with draw.io, parse the xml source file with python and BeautifulSoup and generate a new xml file. The xml tags  are really  straight forward to get.